# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined error with my react login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a login form page that I created using react and typescript, but when I press the submit button, I get this error, why?

I can't see any error in the Code Editor, but when I press the submit button in the browser, it redirects here. I think I made a typescript error but I'm not sure. How can I solve this problem?

**error code**

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/yusuf/Desktop/girisimhaberleriV2.0/src/serializableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:166
  163 |  } = options
  164 | 
  165 |  return storeAPI => next => action => {
> 166 |    if (ignoredActions.length && ignoredActions.indexOf(action.type) !== -1) {
      | ^  167 |      return next(action)
  168 |    }
  169 | 
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/yusuf/Desktop/girisimhaberleriV2.0/frontend/node_modules/redux-thunk/es/index.js:20
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/yusuf/Desktop/girisimhaberleriV2.0/src/immutableStateInvariantMiddleware.ts:257
  254 |        )
  255 |      })
  256 | 
> 257 |      const dispatchedAction = next(action)
      | ^  258 | 
  259 |      measureUtils.measureTime(() => {
  260 |        state = getState()
View compiled
boundActionCreators.<computed>
C:/Users/yusuf/Desktop/girisimhaberleriV2.0/frontend/node_modules/react-redux/es/utils/bindActionCreators.js:9
onSubmit
C:/Users/yusuf/Desktop/girisimhaberleriV2.0/frontend/src/containers/PageLogin/PageLogin.tsx:53
  50 |  const onSubmit = e => {
  51 |      e.preventDefault();
  52 | 
> 53 |      login(email, password);
     | ^  54 |  };
  55 | 
  56 | 
View compiled
onSubmit
C:/Users/yusuf/Desktop/girisimhaberleriV2.0/frontend/src/containers/PageLogin/PageLogin.tsx:94
  91 |   <div className="absolute left-0 w-full top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 border border-neutral-100 dark:border-neutral-800"></div>
  92 | </div>
  93 | {/* FORM */}
> 94 | <form className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6" action="#" method="post" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
     | ^  95 |   <label className="block">
  96 |     <span className="text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200">
  97 |       Email adresiniz
```

**my login form code**

```
import LayoutPage from "components/LayoutPage/LayoutPage";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import facebookSvg from "images/Facebook.svg";
import twitterSvg from "images/Twitter.svg";
import googleSvg from "images/Google.svg";
import Input from "components/Input/Input";
import ButtonPrimary from "components/Button/ButtonPrimary";
import NcLink from "components/NcLink/NcLink";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import { login } from "actions/auth";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


// import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom"
// import {connect} from "react-redux"

export interface PageLoginProps {
  className?: string;
}

const loginSocials = [
  {
    name: "Facebook İle Devam Edin",
    href: "#",
    icon: facebookSvg,
  },
  {
    name: "Twitter İle Devam Edin",
    href: "#",
    icon: twitterSvg,
  },
  {
    name: "Google İle Devam Edin",
    href: "#",
    icon: googleSvg,
  },
];


const Login  = ( {login}:any ) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
      email: '',
      password: '' 
  });

  const { email, password } = formData;

  const onChange = (e:any) => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e:any) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      login(email, password);
  };


  return (
    <div className={`nc-PageLogin`} data-nc-id="PageLogin">
      <Helmet>
      <title>Giriş Yap | Girişim Haberleri</title>
      </Helmet>
      <LayoutPage
        subHeading="Girişim Haberlerine Hoş Geldiniz"
        headingEmoji=""
        heading="Giriş Yapın"
      >
        <div className="max-w-md mx-auto space-y-6">
          <div className="grid gap-3">
            {loginSocials.map((item, index) => (
              <a
                key={index}
                href={item.href}
                className="nc-will-change-transform flex w-full rounded-lg bg-primary-50 dark:bg-neutral-800 px-4 py-3 transform transition-transform sm:px-6 hover:translate-y-[-2px]"
              >
                <img
                  className="flex-shrink-0"
                  src={item.icon}
                  alt={item.name}
                />
                <h3 className="flex-grow text-center text-sm font-medium text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-300 sm:text-sm">
                  {item.name}
                </h3>
              </a>
            ))}
          </div>
          {/* OR */}
          <div className="relative text-center">
            <span className="relative z-10 inline-block px-4 font-medium text-sm bg-white dark:text-neutral-400 dark:bg-neutral-900">
              OR
            </span>
            <div className="absolute left-0 w-full top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 border border-neutral-100 dark:border-neutral-800"></div>
          </div>
          {/* FORM */}
          <form className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6" action="#" method="post" onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
            <label className="block">
              <span className="text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200">
                Email adresiniz
              </span>
              <Input
                type="email"
                placeholder="example@example.com"
                className="mt-1"
                name='email'
                value={email}
                onChange={e => onChange(e)}
              />
            </label>
            <label className="block">
              <span className="flex justify-between items-center text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200">
                Password
                <NcLink to="/forgot-pass" className="text-sm">
                  Forgot password?
                </NcLink>
              </span>
              <Input type="password" className="mt-1" name="password" placeholder="Şifreniz" value={password} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
            </label>
            <ButtonPrimary type="submit">Devam Edin</ButtonPrimary>
          </form>

          {/* ==== */}
          <span className="block text-center text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-300">
            Yeni Misiniz? {` `}
            <NcLink to="/signup">Hemen Hesap Oluşturun.</NcLink>
          </span>
        </div>
      </LayoutPage>
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(null, { login })(Login);
```

Comment: action is undefined, when you try to access type from action `action.type` it crashed

Comment: Which action method are you talking about? Is it form attribute?

Comment: `> 166 |    if (ignoredActions.length && ignoredActions.indexOf(action.type) !== -1) {` This one.